# Getting skin method results in AttributeError

Tags: plone

When I try to call a skin method as follows:

```
portal.skin_method()
```

it results in

```
AttributeError.
```

I remember being able to do this in older versions of Plone.

Has something changed here?

PS: I am able to do:

```
portal.portal_skins.skin_name.skin_method()
```

Comment: Any specific skin method name? Or all of them? It still works for me. Could you include a Plone version, and the full trackback?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior has not changed.

Most likely your portal_skins registration is somehow broken or lost after a theme upgrade.

- Can you confirm you can see skin_method.py in ZMI > portal_skins
- Can you check that this particular skin folder is active in the current theme skin list in ZMI > portal_skins > Properties tab?